# I want to vertically center a fluid image within a container so it appears to zoom in/out

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to center an image vertically within its container so that when the browser width changes and the image grows to max-width of 1500px the image is cropped equally on both the top and bottom. The image has a max-height of 450px no matter the width. I'm not sure it this explanation makes sense.

Here is my CSS code:

```
<style>
    .Center-Container {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #ccc;
        height: 450px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1500px;
    }

    .Absolute-Center {
        width: 100%;
        height: 450px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="Center-Container">
<div class="Absolute-Center">
    <img src="images/coverimage.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

You can view the site here: http://www.concept82.com/center/testcenter.html. Please excuse the current image; I'm using it as a placeholder for the moment. Thanks so much for your time...I'm still a beginner at this!

Comment: Have you already tried any common vertical centering methods? Google will help you

Comment: could you place the image as css background and position it to center?

Comment: I've tried using it as a background image but then the image is no longer fluid and will not scale down as the page width shrinks.

Comment: You can't easily crop a content image. Try making it a background image, use `background-size: cover;` (ex: http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/KaigG) and maybe some media queries to handle different styling for different widths.

Comment: Thanks @KatieK using the background: cover; seems to have worked. I changed my css to this: 
    .Absolute-Center {
 background: url(images/coverimage2.jpg) no-repeat center;
 height: 450px;
 background-size: cover;
}
Then I removed the img tag from the html code. Thanks again...

Comment: @KristinShoffnerTanner - You're welcome. Since this seems to have helped, I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily crop a content image. Try making the image a background image through CSS and using `background-size: cover:`:

```
#image {
  background: #D84E51 url(http://placekitten.com/800/800?image=10) no-repeat center center;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Examples on Codepen: http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/KaigG

Also add some media queries to handle different styling for different viewport widths.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to vertically center an img element. This is a great resource:  [How to crop an image with a CSS class](http://www.squareonemd.co.uk/how-to-crop-an-image-with-a-css-class/)

To vertically center using percentages:

**CSS**

```
.image-cropper {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">
  <p>Center cropped image</p>
  <div class="image-cropper">
    <img class="centered" alt="myimage" src="images/myimage.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```